# Radiobutton Style don't show up as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a very basic form, but I used a third party css which seems to give me a problem. I looked for it pretty long now in this CSS but cannot find anything what cause this problem,

```
  Mevr.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mevr."> 
  Dhr.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dhr.">
   Fam.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Fam.">
```

this is what I expect

[image]

With the third party CSS active I get this:

[image]

My question is: What inline style I can use to get my radiobuttons next to eachother like in the first picture?

note:
the css what cause the problem is [here](http://83.163.140.140//web2016//jscss/rr_style3.css):

Comment: we need check code, we can not help you solve problem without any code

Comment: display: in-line; maybe, but as Radian said you need to share that part of the code or give us a link to your website.

Comment: are you using simple html or asp.net?

Comment: By default the layout should be same as you want you must be using something some css may be because of which your page looks like this

Comment: I suggest you update your post with the **CSS** you're using. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the post with the css

Answer (score 1):

As you have not given the coding.You can try this:

```css
<style>

.some-class {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

label {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 1em 0 0;
}

input[type=radio],
input.radio {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="some-class">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="x" value="y" id="y" />
    <label for="y">Thing 1</label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="x" value="z" id="z" />
    <label for="z">Thing 2</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer.  I've tried this, but still the radiobuttons shows up in a row and not next to eachother   (example)  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/697986/radio3.JPG

Comment: Then it means your third party css overrides this css.You can give different class name

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include the **CSS** in your post it's hard to say what the problem is.

A simple guess would be that the `input`s have a `display` property of `block`. This would cause the line break and possibly other *UI* changes (as seen in your screenshots).

Using `display: inline-block;` would solve this.

```css
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th { 
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
Mevr.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mevr."> 
Dhr.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dhr.">
Fam.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Fam.">
```

**EDIT** As per your updated question, the problems seems to be with the `width` of you `input` tags.

You should try setting your `width` property to `auto`

```css
input {
    border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    padding: 3px 5px 4px;
    color: #979797;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
Mevr.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mevr."> 
Dhr.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Dhr.">
Fam.<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Fam.">
```

Just replace it with the existing one in your **CSS**.

On a side note. I see that your **CSS** has multiple declarations throughout its content. Consider going through it and removing unnecessary declarations.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this one, but it didn't solve it. I've added the CSS in the post

Answer (score 0):

I have used dummy HTML. Try this:

```html
<div style="float: left">
    <input id="RadioButtonList1_0" name="RadioButtonList1" value="One" type="radio"><label for="RadioButtonList1_0">One</label>

    <input id="RadioButtonList1_1" name="RadioButtonList1" value="Two" type="radio"><label for="RadioButtonList1_1">Two</label>

     <input id="RadioButtonList1_2" name="RadioButtonList1" value="Three" type="radio"><label for="RadioButtonList1_2">Three</label>

</div>
```